# drupal module for uploading to s3

Tags: drupal, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal-7, cdn

I have a drupal site and I plan to serve static site files directly from s3 (rewrite).  I need to provide a way for the content manager to upload his images directly to s3 from the drupal admin UI so he doesn't have to send it to me to upload via s3cmd or the aws console.  Can anyone recommend a module or method for this?

I've tried s3fs however mounting a fuse s3 filesystem and serving from it was painfully slow.  If it worked drupal would think the files are all local and i'd be set.

I found this but not sure if it will get the job done for me:
https://drupal.org/project/storage_api

I need a module that would allow the drupal admin UI user to graphically browse for a file (image for instance) to upload to the s3 bucket i intend to serve from.

Comment: This question belongs on drupal.stackexchange.com, the user has already posted a duplicate there

Comment: Answered in Drupal Stackexchange community: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117728/drupal-module-for-uploading-to-s3/120096#120096